# encoding ffmpeg on android with filter is slow

Tags: video, cpu, ffmpeg, android, gpu

I am using ffmpeg on android to crop, compress, resize video.
This all works fine in terms of speed.

But when I try adding filters, e.g.

`colorchannelmixer=.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3` for grayscale, encoding works slowly. About 1 frame per second.

Is there a way to speed this up? Maybe specify to use GPU.

Comment: Share your full command.

Comment: @Gyan `-threads 2 -y -i input.mp4 -movflags faststart -strict experimental -filter_complex colorchannelmixer=.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3 -map 0:a -vcodec mpeg4 -crf 23 -b:v 1000K -maxrate 1500K -bufsize 500K -t 00:03:00.0 -preset veryfast output.mp4`

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
-threads 2 -y -i input.mp4 -t 3:00 -vf format=gray,format=yuv420p -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 1000K -maxrate 1500K -bufsize 500K -movflags faststart -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Should be faster, since the color channel mixer will call a scaler to convert the input to a RGB format, then carry out the operation per pixel. Then, due to the encoder constraint, another scaler call is made to convert to YUV420P. My first format simply discards the chroma planes.

Comment: I use colorchannelmixer for other filters too. For example, sepia

Comment: Would you be able to explain the difference between your options and the original and *why* it is faster?

Comment: @Gyan thanks for this. I will try this on grayscale.